# How to make .ascx properties settable in .aspx files

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control that has a public property defined in the code-behind (.ascx.cs). Is there a way for this property to be set directly inside the tag of the .aspx file that the control is being used? I can already access the property in the code-behind of the .aspx file.

Comment: Easy: Make then (the properties) public.

Comment: They already are public. I can set them dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something obvious, then it's easy...

```
<uc1:MyCtrl runat="server" MyVal="this value" />
```

Comment: The attribute/property didn't show up in intelliSense and the attribute was not reflected.

Comment: @Alex, not reflected? You mean the value isn't being passed into the parameter?

Comment: @Alex, if it's not working then there must be something else wrong in your code/page. Make sure your Register declaration is pointing to the correct usercontrol, that the control is using the correct codebehind class, and that your property is doing exactly what you expect it to do

Comment: Yes, the property's set "block" updates the text of a control inside my usercontrol

Comment: @Alex, have you put a breakpoint within the property and checked to see if it hits it? Sorry, but it's very simple ASP.NET syntax, there must be something else causing an issue

Comment: Could setting the property in the tag cause the value to be set too early in the page lifecyle (the property *directly* sets another tag prtoperty). The property value gets sent correctly (the result displays in the browser) when setting the variable in the Page_Load event.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14098/discussion-between-alex-juan-gittemeier-and-freefaller)

Comment: @Alex, apologies, I'd left for the night when you sent the chat request. Tag properties are set at the very start of the lifecycle on initial load (viewstate takes over on post-backs)... please read [this article on Understanding ASP.NET ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx). Make sure you are not overwriting it in your Page_Load

Comment: Found the issue. when i set the breakpoint, i realized that I (erroneously) was using the public property name in place of "value". +1 and the answer for your help.